# How to call an item from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary which consists of a number and its definition is the corresponding element on the periodic table.

I have built up the dictionary like this:

```
for line in open("periodic_table.txt"):
    temp.append(line.rstrip())

for t in temp:
    if t[1] != " ":
        elements[x] = t[3:]
    else:
        elements[x] = t[2:]
    x += 1
```

I know that every element is in table because I ask the program to print the dictionary.
The point of this is that the user enters a number or element name and the number and name are both printed like this:

```
while count == 0:
    check = 0
    line = input("Enter element number or element name: ")
    if line == "":
        count = count + 1
        break
    for key,value in elements.items():
        if line == value:
            print ("Element number for",line,"is",key)
            check = 1
            break
        if line.isdigit():
            if int(line) <= 118 and int(line) > 0:
                print ("Element number",line, "is",elements[int(line)])
                check = 1
                break
    if check == 0:
        print ("That's not an element!")
```

This works for every element except the last one, Ununoctium, in the dictionary. When the user enters 118 this element is printed, but if they enter 'ununoctium' then the program says "That is not an element!". Why is this and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if they enter Ununoctium instead?

Comment: is there a problem with capitalisation? Try `line.lower()` to ensure the user input is all lower case. (and `value.lower()` for the other side of the test)

Comment: you can use pprint.pprint(the_dictionary) to manually check what do you have in your dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to have python do the lookup for you. Ignoring empty lines for now:

```
elements = []
for line in open("periodic_table.txt"):
    elements.append(line[3:])
```

You can then do a lookup like this:

```
if answer.isdigit():
    print elements[int(answer)]
else:
    print elements.index(answer)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is a case sensitive issue.

Changing

```
if line == value:
```

to

```
if line.lower() == value.lower():
```

would solve that problem.

While you are there, why have the `if` inside the `for` loop?
You could check that first, and then don't need the `break`

```
if line.isdigit():
    if int(line) <= 118 and int(line) > 0:
        print ("Element number",line, "is",elements[int(line)])
        check = 1 
        #<-------- break no longer required
else:
    #for loop as above
```

Comment: I made some changes and am pretty sure it is not a case sensitive issue.

Comment: "Some changes" == these changes?

Comment: Yes the changes you suggested above, but that was not the issue and I have since solved it! The issue was that when the program was building the dictionary it was adding white space in front of the elements that  had a 3 digit number, and since the user doesn't enter a white space when entering the element name the program would consider this as incorrect, therefore declaring this as "not an element."